# How to add sub categories to Magento Blog

Tags: magento-1.9, blog

I have searched lot in google i have not found any extension for the Magento blog with functionality of parent category and child category.
Currently I am using this blog extension
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blog-6.html.
I don't know how to add the child category to parent category in magento blog.
Can any pls help me for the implemention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [**Better blog By Mage Plaza**](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-blog/)

You can create child category in blog way you create category in magento.

**[Clone it from Git.](https://github.com/ergopalpatel/Blog--Magento)**

Comment: can send you me the  link for  extension

Comment: already there.. Click on `Beeter blog By Mage Plaza`  its anchor @prashanth

Comment: there no  file to download extension

Comment: upps looks like they just removed that extension @prashanth

Comment: @prashanth git link added

Comment: @thankyou gopal for the link , let me check

Comment: can you tell how to show the category for the post in recent post

Comment: I have to look into it and currently not having any demo magento setup  @prashanth Will try to solve your query  in free time

Comment: Can I know how to change the URL of category in magento blog existing url : https://www.example.com/category/fitness-and-wellness to new url : https://www.example.com/blog/fitness-and-wellness

Comment: System->configuration->Mageplaza->Better Blog->category->add URL suffix @prashanth